# Appium API endpoints

Tags: webdriver, appium

In the Appium wiki page (https://github.com/appium/appium/wiki/Automating-mobile-gestures) the following endpoints are mentioned:

1. session/:sessionId/touch/tap
2. session:/sessionId/touch/flick_precise
3. session:/sessionId/touch/swipe

However, when using TouchActions of the newest Java bindings of WebDriver (2.35):

1. A call to **"singleTap"**, calls  /touch/click (i.e., not "tap"). Which, in my application at least, causes the Appium server to output an error and drop the client without notifying it, so the client just hangs.
2. A call to **"flick"**, calls /touch/flick (instead of "flick_precis"), which works fine.

Which is endpoints are correct? The ones written in the documnentation or the java bindings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The JSON-wire-protocol is currently being adapted to support all the mobile actions. For now here is the documentation on how to do this.

[Appium Gestures Documentation](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/gestures.md)

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the reply. My question was regarding the contradiction I noticed between the documentation and the actual calls made by Appium using Java bindings (e.g., "click" is called instead of "tap"). So I was wondering if that is a bug or just undocumented way Appium implementation? Moreover, I get an error when using "singleTap" from the TouchActions in Java bindings - call to click causes the client to hang. Thanks.

Comment: This is all up in the air right now, I recommend using regular selenium non-touch click for now. iOS Driver, Appium, and Selendroid are currently working on JSON wire protocol extensions to properly support appium

Answer (score 0):

May be this C# function that sends Fingerprint to Android emulator will help to someone.
fingerprintId = "1" - parameter that you need to configure in Android device in Settings.

```
        string session_id = Program.Params.androidDriver.SessionId.ToString();

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/" + session_id + "/appium/device/finger_print");

        request.Method = "POST";            
        request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";


        var my_jsondata = new
        {
            fingerprintId = "1"
        };

        var postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(my_jsondata);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        dataStream.Close();
```